Как получить координаты остановок ОТ
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить данные об автобусной остановке, по которой я кликнул? Мне необходимо составить маршрут, состоящий из остановок ОТ(с их названиями). Для построения маршрута используется multiRouter с настройкой routingMode: 'auto', но при установке точек я получаю координаты и название ближайшей улицы, на которой стоит остановка. Так же пробовал менять настройку на routingMode: 'masstransit' - тоже ситуацию не изменило.
Также пытался реализовать задачу через поиск ближайших остановок от точки с помощью api Яндекс.Расписание по этому примеру Яндекс-Карты. Узнать название ближайшей остановки общественного транспорта
В результате запрос https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/nearest_stations/?apikey={ВАШ_КЛЮЧ}&format=json&lat=59.131296395386464&lng=37.922166399657556&distance=10&station_types=bus_stop&lang=ru_RU&transport_types=bus
в котором я должен получить список конкретно автобусных остановок и конкретно для автобусов относительно заданной точки возвращает одну-единственную привокзальную площадь в радиусе 10(!!!) километров, что, конечно мало похоже на правду)
Отсюда возникает вопрос - можно ли вообще как-то получать данные об остановке при клике на нее(чтобы в метку сразу записалось именно название остановки), либо, если есть какие-то ограничения api карт, какими средствами можно реализовать данную задачу?

API Яндекс Карт не имеет методов для получения информации об остановках. Такая информация доступна только в приложениях Яндекс.
